# Can't connect to the new OneDrive. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, onedrive

Since Microsoft has announced its switch from Skydrive to OneDrive, I (along with my teammates here at work) have been been unable to connect to the website.  Everyone can access OneDrive from home, but something at work is blocking it and IT is saying that they don't block anything. Like I mentioned before, everything was fine prior to yesterday.

We can all access it fine via the SkyDrive app in Windows 8.x or from the iOS app.  But the website is inaccessible.

In Chrome, I get this error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  When I hook in Fiddler, I get ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED in Chrome.  In Fiddler, I can see that Chrome is trying to tunnel into onedrive.live.com:443, but the result is `[Fiddler] The socket connection to onedrive.live.com failed. <br />ErrorCode: 10061. <br />No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:443`.  Basically stating that the socket connection to onedrive.live.com has failed.

Once in a while (and I have no idea if this is related), Fiddler comes up with the following message box:

[image]

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does the network your connected to replace signed certificates with its own? Based on the error message this is a certificate problem which should be resolved by asking IT.

Comment: "127.0.0.1:443" stikes me as odd. Like it's resolving live.com to your computer.  Do you use a proxy?   Have you checked your hosts file for an entry for live.com?  Tried disabling all anit-malware software?  Tried Safe Mode with Networking?  If you do an NSLookup does it resolve the right IP address?  How about Ping, does it resolve the right address?  How far does a TraceRt make it?

Comment: Can you access other MS services, like mail.live.com (Outlook) or people.live.com? Have you tried other browsers besides Chrome?

Comment: @techie007 All these tools resolve to 127.0.0.1 - so you got something there.  We all have Symantec Endpoint Protection and no way to disable it.  Tracert goes straight to 127.0.0.1 and says trace complete.  Ping also goes directly to 127.0.0.1.  Nslookup specifies my DNS for the Server entry and 127.0.0.1 for Address.

Comment: @Indrek Yes, I can access ALL other MS services no problem.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution, but try adding the following entry into your hosts file: `157.56.128.254 onedrive.live.com` (that's the IP I get from NSLookup and tracert).

Comment: @Indrek Your suggestion seems to have gotten me halfways there.  Now the page loads, but the files don't show up.  I looked in fiddler and it tries to go to `skyapi.onedrive.live.com`, which also resolves to 127.0.0.1.  Would you mind getting the IP address for this URL as well, so that I can add it to my hosts file?

Comment: @Indrek Never mind, I got the IP address - thank you for your insightful comment.

Comment: No problem. Looks like _something_ on your network is redirecting the traffic to 127.0.0.1 (aka localhost). I'd try taking this up with your IT department again, because to me it looks like the problem is not on your computer.

Comment: @Indrek You are right on the money.  I presented them with the `hosts` solution and then they changed something and it all works now perfectly.